# how i can add a value in a command using php on linux

Tags: php, linux, bash, terminal

how i can add a value in a command using php on linux
for example

in bash :
`>> bash example.sh test`
i can print 'test' with : 
`printf $1`
result :
`test`

in python :
`>> python example.py test`
i can print 'test' with : 
`print (sys.argv[1])`
result :
`test`

i need this operation on php
if i use the command `>> php index.php test` in terminal on linux
i need to see the result `test`

Comment: `echo $argv[1];` or `print`.  Also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

Comment: thanks bro it's working